# Python variable substitution

Tags: python, list, variables

I have a script that calls a list of linux guests I am trying to tidy up.  Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


guests = ['guest1','guest2','guest3','guest*']
def serverCheck(guestList)
    for g in guestList:
        server = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=tstenvironment,node=guest1,name=uatenvironment,type=Server,*')
        try:
            status = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'state')
            print g + status
        except:
            print "Error %s is down." % g
serverCheck(guests)
```

The problem lies in this line:

```
server = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=Afcutst,node=%s,name=afcuuat1,type=Server,*') % g
```

How do I use my list to populate the node variable while still being able to pass the info within the parentheses to the AdminControl function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument string itself is the argument to the `%` operator, not the return value of the function call.

```
server = AdminControl.completeObjectName(
    'cell=Afcutst,node=%s,name=afcuuat1,type=Server,*' % (g,)
)
```

---

Peeking into the crystal ball, Python 3.6 will allow you to write

```
server = AdminControl.completeObjectName(
    f'cell=Afcutst,node={g},name=afcuuat1,type=Server,*'
)
```

embedding the variable directly into a special *format* string literal.

Answer (score 0):

can you try like this

```
AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell=tstenvironment,node=%s,name=uatenvironment,type=Server,*'%g)
```

Answer (score 0):

For more readability I would suggest this and also using the same way to format strings from variables (here I chose `str.format`)

```
guests = ['guest1','guest2','guest3','guest*']

def serverCheck(guestList)
    name_tpl = 'cell=tstenvironment,node={},name=uatenvironment,type=Server,*'

    for g in guestList:
        obj_name = name_tpl.format(g)
        server = AdminControl.completeObjectName(obj_name)
        try:
            status = AdminControl.getAttribute(server, 'state')
            print '{}: {}'.format(g, status)
        except:
            print 'Error {} is down'.format(g)

serverCheck(guests)
```